# Update value for the "threshold input" in the "Switch Block" in MATLAB dynamically that is I require user-based input as my threshold value

Tags: matlab

How to update value for the "threshold input" in the "Switch Block" in MATLAB dynamically? that is I require user-based input as my threshold value.

Comment: Is this simulink related? What do you mean dynamically/user input? How are you requiring a user input? is it a Real time simulink model? You need to add more explanations

Comment: Actually,I am designing a counter that counts until a user-provided value. The problem statement says if the user provided value is met, the counter must output the provided value. Eg: If you enter a value of 10, the counter must count to 10 and after the tenth unit time it must display 10 as the output. Now it is easy to implement the counter. I have taken a constant(1) and incremented it after every sample time. To limit the count I used a switch block with the condition as "current value<user provided value". I need to change this user provided input dynamically. Hope this made it clear.

Comment: Why dont you just make a comparator in the input? Make the trheshold =0.5, but make the switch input the output of a comparator

Comment: The switch block has three inputs - 1 control signal, 2 inputs. If the control satisfies the condition provided in the switch block input 1 is the output or else input two. So, what you are saying is completely different. Maybe you didn't understand correctly.

Comment: Please consider describing your problem better and showing a n example. [edit] your question